# Does this simulate fluid dynamics well?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, simulations, bernoulli-equation

Consider a 2d simulation which consists of thousands of tiny circles bouncing off each other in elastic, frictionless collisions. Particles are thrown into the simulation from the left side of the screen at some velocity and eventually exit through the right side.

My question is: To what degree do you expect this simulation to simulate the behavior of an ideal gas (or fluids in general)? For example, if the walls were shaped to various cross-sectional areas, do you think Bernoulli's Principle would be visible, such that at narrow regions the flow velocity would be greater and the pressure the particles exerted on the walls would be less, and vice-versa for wider sections?

Let me know any way I can clarify, or if it would help to see the actual simulation. Thanks

Comment: Gas: maybe. Fluid : No. It's clear that for a fluid more properties must emerge like surface tension, viscosity, etc. One ingredient what's missing it's weak inter-molecular attraction forces, but even then i'm not sure if that's enough.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas A gas is a fluid. You seem to be referring to liquids.

Comment: @electronpusher Indeed. But it doesn't change the meaning. OPs simulation may define only part of fluids (not liquids for sure).